Will power strips/extension cords from China work in Mexico? Sorry for the stupid question
First, I want to apologize for asking the pros here what I'm sure will be a ridiculously simple/stupid question.  I did a google search and read forums with similar questions, but I wanted to be 100% sure I'm not getting anecdotal or assumed knowledge but instead getting the facts from the experts.
I'm a tech heavy user and I move around a lot between countries.  For my international move between China to Argentina, both 220-240V countries, I brought a dozen power strips and extension cords.  Some needed plug adapters to fit, but otherwise there were no problems.  Now I'm moving to Mexico, which is a 120-140V country.  I'd like to know if I can continue to use these strips and cords (with the appropriate plug adapter of course, I know the outlets are different)?  I'm under the assumption that because they are rated for a higher wattage, then being plugged into to an electrical system with half that rating shouldn't be an issue, but like I said, I'd like to know factually if they would work or if they'll be useless.
For example, most of the power strips I have say something like:
10A 250W
2500W-10A MAX 250V~
2000W 10A(13A)MAX 250V~ 50Hz
~200W 6A 250V~ (single extension cord, not a strip)
6A 250V, on cable it says 300/300V (single extension cord)
Would it be safe to use them in Mexico, or do I have to toss them?
Thanks again for any help (and please forgive me for my ignorance).
PS. I understand the voltage of the items being plugged in must be according to that of the country otherwise they'll be fried.  I would be plugging 120V rated equipment into the strips/cords.

There are two plugs (mainly) used in mainland China ex. HK/Macao - a non-polarized two-blade type that is much like the Canada/US plug but without the little holes at the end of the blades, and a three blade type that is very similar to Australian type. From here

Chinese (domestic market) power bars are designed to take either type of plug so they will accept some US/Canada/Mexico style plugs (the unpolarized two pin ones- the polarized ones have one wider leg and won't fit the Chinese power bars). They will also accept European style two round pin (no ground) plugs.
Here are a couple decent quality ones I own:

Electrically the strips themselves, if good quality, should not be an issue when used within their current limits (the power limit will be half because of the lower Mexican voltage).
But.. the business end of the power strips is a Type I three pin plug and would require a type I socket to type B adapter to plug into the wall in Mexico.
Mexico (like Canada and the US) uses type A and B plugs  from here:

The Chinese power strips won't accept type B plugs  so you'd need type I plug to type B socket adapters to get the ground connection. Type A plugs would only fit if they are non-polarized, otherwise they could use the same adapter.
Approvals aside, this would be a bit of a mess and I think you'd be better off just spending a few dollars on a North American standard power bar at Walmart or whatever.
Most of the adapters that are sold, even at reputable shops in North America are not safety approved to be used anywhere. There might be some risk with the octopus of adapters and power bars with bad connections and overheating etc. Certainly more risk than straightforward connections. You could also have issues with power loss with cascaded adapters etc. Some adapters do not pass through a ground and that is a safety risk and some devices may not operate quite properly without the ground.
TL;DR: Buy a power bar for North America
... but consider keeping the Chinese ones along if you have to use 120:240 adapter (autotransformer) and devices designed for 240V mains.

Apparently this topic is closed so I can't directly reply, but I just wanted to say THANK YOU SO MUCH for your detailed reply.  I took detailed notes, with the pictures you provided (was hard to get my head around the different types at first) and I finally understand.  I wish it were as easy as spending a few dollars on a standard power bar, but probably is I need like 10 of them, and at the prices I'm seeing online, that'll cost me a couple hundred dollars.  Would have been nice to spend $20 on a handful of adapters and bring the ones I already have.  I see your point though.  Thanks again!

@Spixe Unfortunately this question does not fit perfectly in any of the four SE sites where it is a candidate. Too technical for travel or expats, too specific to China for DIY and too use-oriented for here. So it gets closed without being migrated. Making sure grounds get connected is one key point. Maybe you can do a hybrid solution, buy one or two new ones.

No worries, I wasn't sure it would ever get seen in the first place and was ready for it to get deleted if it wasn't allowed. I'm just thankful you had a change to reply before that. I'll try to sell most of the extension cords I have to make up for the loss of buying new ones too.  Where I live now, they are somewhat expensive, so maybe I'll get some bites.  Good idea about the hybrid solution too, I could plug some of the bigger more expensive ones I have into some I buy in Mexico to make sure it gets a ground connection, rather than using an adapter. Again, thanks a ton, you're a lifesaver!
